# R Studio F2 wont initiate `View()` anymore

Tags: r, rstudio

When I hit `F2` on my keyboard it'll open up a data frame in an Excel type fashion. But sometimes it opens this (see image below) instead. What went wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the keyboard shortcut [document](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts), F2 is to show the source code for function at cursor. If you highlight (or position the cursor on) a dataframe variable and press F2, the data viewer will open and you will see that the `View(df)` command ran in the console. Similarly, if you highlight or position on a function name, you will see the source code of that function.

Comment: In other words, there was no data.frame called `df` defined in your global environment when you pressed `F2`, so RStudio instead fell back and discovered the definition of a function called `df()` in the stats package instead.

Comment: @Kevin Ushey I did define `df <- mtcars` but it seems *R Studio* defaults to `F2` opening the function view, if your variable also is a function name somewhere (in this case `stats::df`).

Comment: You're right! We should consider changing that behavior.