# R Studio `F2` and `View()` producing two different results

Tags: r, rstudio

```
df <- mtcars
View(df)
```

The code above results in the image below (what I expect) and also prints `df <- mtcars` and `View(df)` to my console.

[image]

If I then highlight `df` in my console and press <kbd>F2</kbd> I get the image below. And nothing is output to my console.

[image]

<kbd>F2</kbd> is supposed to be equivalent to `View()` and it usually is. Right now I can highlight `mtcars`, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, and I get the spreadsheet view. `df` is showing as a data.frame in my global environment, yet <kbd>F2</kbd> thinks it is a function.

[image]

Why won't <kbd>F2</kbd> work when I highlight this particular `df` that I just defined as `df <- mtcars`?

Comment: Also, why did you re-ask this question when you already received and accepted a well-worded answer? [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655772/r-studio-f2-wont-initiate-view-anymore)

Comment: Using `df` as the name of a dataframe is [occasionally problematic in other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50163004/4996248). Having said that, I still do it all the time. Old habits are hard to break.

Comment: @C.Braun I agree that this is a duplicate although it was probably intended more as a follow up. The problem is that the accepted answer falsely suggests that *after* you define `df` as a dataframe, then `F2` will revert to `View(df)`. It doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a built-in function called `df` from the `stats` package. Pressing `f2` is primarily for showing the source code of a function, and will only do the equivalent of `View` if the variable is not a function.

If you really use this a lot you may need to use a different name for your variables.